# Detecting Single Quotes in free marker

Tags: regex, freemarker

I'm trying to write a regex which detects both

`href="http(s)://somelink"` and `href='http(s)://somelink'` .

I have the following regex which i am using right now:

```
<#assign res = htmlBody?matches(r'href="http(s?)(.+?)"')>
```

which detects the first case perfectly. 
 Using regex 101, i found that using this regex :

```
href=('|")http(s?)(.+?)('|")
```

Would work fine with both cases. 
but, using

```
<#assign res = htmlBody?matches(r'href=(\'|")http(s?)(.+?)(\'|")')>
```

Or
<#assign res = htmlBody?matches(r'href=('|")http(s?)(.+?)('|")')>
Or

```
 <#assign res = htmlBody?matches(r'href=(\\'|")http(s?)(.+?)(\\'|")')>
```

> Results in the same error: Error(s) rendering template:
>   core.templating.TemplateMergeException at
>   null,null:Exception parsing template.; nested exception is
>   freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "HTML" in
>   line 19, column 33: Found string literal: r'href=(\'. Expecting:
>   boolean (true/false)

it doesn't seem to detect the single quotes. 
Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using the raw string literal, try using just the string and escape the single  quotes. Try `<#assign res = htmlBody?matches('href=([\'"])https?(?:.+?)\\1')>` which uses a backreference to what is captured in group 1

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: hi @Thefourthbird, yes that worked perfectly! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I have added it as an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the raw string literal, you could use just the string, escape the single quotes and update the regex to `href=([\'"])https?.+?\\1` which makes use of a capturing group.

You code would look like:

```
<#assign res = htmlBody?matches('href=([\'"])https?.+?\\1')>
```

Regex details:

- `href=` Match literally
- `([\'"])` Capturing group 1 which matches either `'` or `"`
- `https?` Match http with optional s
- `.*?` Match any character non greedy
- `\\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1